# iOS - UIRefreshControl crash

Tags: ios, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

If I "pull to refresh" my `UITableViewController` with a quick flick of the finger (rather than a slow drag and release), my app crashes with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x30000008)` error.

Here is the relevant code:

```
- (void)refreshView:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self populateWhatsOn];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
            [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        });
    });
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also, turning on NSZombie found the following, which I can't interpret:  Terminating app due to uncaught exception of class '_NSZombie_NSException'
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: Were you able to find a fix for this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: I have same issue, any one can fix?

Comment: Could you post the `-populateWhatsOn` method? I think the answer lies there.

Comment: Same problem here, but it happens when I pull it too far. Any help?

Comment: How are you setting up your refresh control?

Answer (score -1):

Check if `populateWhatsOn` uses properties also referenced in `endRefreshing`. If so create a separate queue and execute any common changes into this queue.